# Counting the length of the Collatz sequence - custom iterator produces slowdown?

Tags: c++, performance, iterator

I've been solving the UVA problem #100 - ["The 3n + 1 problem"](https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=36). This is their "sample" problem, with a very forgiving time limit (limit of 3 sec, their [sample solution](https://uva.onlinejudge.org/data/p100.c.html) with no caching at all runs in 0.738 sec, my best solution so far run in 0.016 sec), so I thought however I'd experiment with the code, I should always fit in the limit. Well, I was mistaken.

The problem specification is simple: each line of input has two numbers `i` and `j`, and the output should print these numbers followed by the maximum length of the Collatz sequence whose beginning is in between `i` and `j` inclusive.

I've prepared four solutions. They are quite similar and all produce good answers.

[The first solution](http://ideone.com/CEgpur) caches up to `0x100000` sequence lengths in a `vector`. Length of `0` means the length for the sequence that starts at this particular number has not yet been calculated. It runs fast enough - 0.03 sec.

[The second solution](http://ideone.com/k8YvIH) is quite similar, only it caches every singe length in a sparse array implemented with an `unordered_map`. It runs fairly slower than the previous solution, but still fits well in the limit: 0.28 sec.

As an exercise, I also wrote [the third solution](http://ideone.com/06etzG), which based on the second one. The goal was to use the `max_element` function, which only accepts iterators. I couldn't use `unordered_map::iterator`, for incrementing such iterator is, AFAIK, linear in map size; therefore, I wrote a custom iterator, operating on an abstract "container" that "holds" the sequence length of every possible number (but in fact calculates them and caches them only as needed). In it's core, it's actually the same `unordered_map` solution - only there's an extra layer of iterators added on the top. The solution did not fit in the 3 sec. limit.

And now comes the thing I can't understand. While obviously the third solution is overcomplicated on purpose, I could hardly believe that an extra layer of iterators could produce such a slowdown. To check this out, I added a same iterator layer to the `vector` solution. This is [my fourth solution](http://ideone.com/Gzu3KH). Judging from what this iterator idea did to my `unordered_map` solution, I expected a considerable slowdown here as well; but oddly enough, this did not happen at all. This solution runs almost as fast as the plain `vector` one, in 0.035 sec.

How is this possible? What exactly is responsible for the slowdown in the third solution? How is it possible that overcomplicating two similar solutions in an exactly the same way slows one of them down very much, and hardly harms the other at all? Why adding the iterator layer to the `unordered_map` solution made it not fitting in time, and doing the same to the `vector` solution hardly slowed it down at all?

EDIT:

I found out that the problem seems to be most visible if the input contains many repetitive lines. I tested all four solutions on my machine against the input of `1 1000000`, repeated 200 times. The solution with a plain vector processed all of them in 1.531 sec. The solution with the vector and the additional iterator layer took 3.087 sec. The solution with the plain unordered map took 33.821 sec. And the solution with the unordered map and the additional iterator layer managed took more than **half an hour** - I halted it after 31 minutes 0.482 sec! I tested it on Linux mint 17.2 64 bit, g++ version Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04 with flags -std=c++11 -O2, processor Celeron 2955U @1.4 GHz x 2

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. The third solution completes in negligible time on my machine for the given program and input. (`time` reports 1-2 ms.) Same for the second. Perhaps post a harder input file?

Comment: … changing the last line to `900 1000000` increases the times to the 1 sec range: The third solution completes in 1 sec and the second one completes in 2 sec. Doesn't seem too sensitive to optimization level or GCC vs. Clang, either.

Comment: @Potatoswatter UVA works like this: you present them the source file, they compile it and run on their machine, feeding your program with their input, which is usually fairly hard. If your program fails to finish within their time limits (3 sec here), they judge it as incorrect. Unfortunately, they keep their input secret, so I can't post it here. They do publish some "sample input" - which is what I've posted here - but it is usually so lightweight it is hardly suitable for any testing. The times I've posted are the times the solutions took running on their server and their input.

Comment: @Potatoswatter I run the program on my machine against the input of `1 1000000`. Results: Solution with a plain `vector`: 0.046 sec; Solution with `vector` and iterators: 0.064 sec; Solution with `unordered_map`: 1.26 sec; And solution with `unordered_map` and the extra iterator layer: 2.656 sec. BTW are you sure in your input the third solution completed faster than the second one? That would be interesting... how could adding those iterators actually speed up execution time?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that solution #2 (`unordered_map` only) is twice as fast as #3 (plus `lengthsbase::iterator`) on my machine. I don't know why. I'm using GCC 5.1 and Clang 3.6 on OS X, on a Haswell 2.3 GHz Core i7 Macbook. Anyway, even if your numbers are 2:1 in the other direction, that's still a completely different result lacking the surprise of what the online judge said.

Comment: My point isn't so much about what inputs are used by the online judge, as what you believe that we here on SO should use. It's better not to have each answerer design their own test.

Comment: Eek, that other comment was backwards. Not "twice as fast," it's "twice as long." I double checked. For real.

Comment: @Potatoswatter I tested all four solutions against the input of `1 1000000`, repeated 200 times. Plain vector: 1.531 sec; vector with iterators: 3.087 sec; plain unordered map: 33.821 sec; unordered map with iterators: I dunno, halted it after 31 minutes 0.482 sec. Linux mint 17.2 64 bit, g++ version Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04 with flags -std=c++11 -O2, processor Celeron 2955U @1.4 GHz x 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It [appears to be](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/lEMT73ebEnjQJFyu#wandbox-resultwindow-code-body-11) a problem in GCC 4.8. It doesn't occur in 4.9 up. For some reason, subsequent outer loops (with the populated `unordered_map` cache) run progressively slower, not faster. I'm not sure why, since the `unordered_map` isn't getting bigger.

If you follow that link and switch GCC 4.8 to 4.9, then you'll see the expected behavior where subsequent runs over the same numeric range add little time because they leverage the cache.

Altogether, the philosophy of being "conservative" with compiler updates has been outdated for a long time. Compilers today are rigorously tested and you should use the latest (or at least some recent) release for everyday development.

For an online judge to subject you to long-fixed bugs is just cruel.

Comment: Thank you very much. Indeed, the judge says itself it uses "*4.8.2 - GNU C++ Compiler with options: -lm -lcrypt -O2 -std=c++11 -pipe -DONLINE_JUDGE" for C++11. As of me, I'm just using the standard version from the standard repositories... I'd have to enable backports if I were to upgrade my compiler I'm afraid...

Comment: Also please see this benchmark I made: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/XRocZilmeRupsDk9 Here we have the opposite situation: gcc 4.8.2 produces a program that runs in ~7 sec, while gcc 4.9.0 and *even* gcc 5.2.0 and ***even*** gcc 6.0.0 produces a program that gets killed by Wandbox for running too long.  The benchmark is somewhat similar to the problem discussed here.

Comment: BTW Clang 3.6.0 seems to be doing just fine in both Wandbox links.